# Save points cloud in PLOT3D format

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have the following function to save points cloud in PLOT3D format:

```py
def write(filename, mesh):
    """
    Write the mesh to filename in PLOT3D format.
    filename: is the name of the output file.
    mesh: is a numpy array of size (N,2) or (N, 3) where N is the number of points. mesh[i] is a numpy array coordinates of the i'th point.

    """
    points = mesh.points
    imax = np.unique(points[:, 0]).size
    jmax = np.unique(points[:, 1]).size

    _2d = False
    if points.shape[1] == 2:
        _2d = True
    elif np.unique(points[:, 2]).size == 1:
        _2d = True

    with open(filename, "w") as p3dfile:
        if not _2d:
            kmax = np.unique(points[:, 2]).size
            print(imax, jmax, kmax, file=p3dfile)
            for value in points.flatten(order="F"):
                print(value, file=p3dfile)
        else:
            print(imax, jmax, file=p3dfile)
            for value in points[:, 0:2].flatten(order="F"):
                print(value, file=p3dfile)
```

For large number of points this function is very slow.

I appreciate any suggestion to improve the code above.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! A few quick questions that came to my mind reading your question: How slow is slow? How fast do you need/expect it to be? Have you already done sone profiling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Optimizations/improvements:

*Namings*

- `write` is too generic name for specific function. The one of better names is **`write_points`**
- `_2d`. Even if a variable is marked as "protected" `_...`, starting its name with a digit is a bad naming pattern. As it's a *boolean* flag a meaningful name would be **`is_2dim`** (*is 2-dimensional space*)

Since `mesh` argument is only used to access its inner property `points` it's better to pass the target *points* data structure directly (It's called *Replace Query with Parameter* technique)

In current approach, when reaching the condition `if not _2d:` the expression `np.unique(points[:, 2]).size` will be calculated repeatedly, instead: 
since `points` array is expected to be *2d* array with either 2 or 3 columns we can collect *unique counts* across all columns at once (instead of declaring `imax`, `jmax`):

```
col_counts = [np.unique(row).size for row in points.T]
```

The whole conditional:

```
_2d = False
if points.shape[1] == 2:
    _2d = True
elif np.unique(points[:, 2]).size == 1:
    _2d = True
```

is now replaced with a single statement:

```
is_2dim = points.shape[1] == 2 or col_counts[2] == 1
```

Calling `print` function at each iteration to write the data into file:

```
for value in points.flatten(order="F"):
    print(value, file=p3dfile)
```

is definitely **less** efficient and performant than calling [**`writelines()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.writelines) on *generator* expression at once.

---

The final optimized function:

```
def write_points(filename, points):
    """
    Write the mesh points to filename in PLOT3D format.
    filename: is the name of the output file.
    mesh: is a numpy array of size (N,2) or (N, 3) where N is the number of points. mesh[i] is a numpy array coordinates of the i'th point.

    """
    col_counts = [np.unique(row).size for row in points.T]
    is_2dim = points.shape[1] == 2 or col_counts[2] == 1

    with open(filename, "w") as p3dfile:
        pd3file.write(' '.join(map(str, col_counts)))
        pd3file.writelines(f'{num}\n' for num in points.flatten(order="F"))
```